# angular ui router setting the page title

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI Router for routing between a hybrid (angularjs and angular) app, to that end I'm using the following

```
export const homeState: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
    name: 'home.about',
    component: HomeComponent
};
```

How do I set the title of the page through this, I tried adding an additional attribute `title: 'titleName'` but this did not work, I also tried adding the same attribute to the `params` property as well without any luck.  Any suggestions anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `Title` Service Provided by angular

```
// Import the native Angular services.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template:
  `<p>
    Select a title to set on the current HTML document:
  </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

here is a running [Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qlxjeldgnmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

For more refer to [Angulat Docs](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title)